# What is the best way to begin transactions?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

I have installed cron on server who runs each 3 minutes some functions.

this are functions:

```
$xmldb->sendOddsToDb();
$xmldb->copyHAtoHandicap();
$xmldb->sendFixturesToDb();
$xmldb->fillBaby();
```

Each function has:

```
try{
$this->conn->connect(); //connect to database
$this->PDO->beginTransaction(); // begin
$stmt = $this->PDO->prepare($this->insTLS); 
//some params not important
$this->PDO->commit(); //SAVE
$this->conn->close(); //CLOSE
}
catch(Exception $e){
$this->PDO->rollBack(); 
}
```

Now my question, is better to use transactions like this, for each function new transaction or is better to start just once, and commit on end of all functions?
For example:

```
try{
    $this->conn->connect(); //connect to database
    $this->PDO->beginTransaction(); // begin
    $xmldb->sendOddsToDb();
    $xmldb->copyHAtoHandicap();
    $xmldb->sendFixturesToDb();
    $xmldb->fillBaby();
    $this->PDO->commit(); //SAVE
    $this->conn->close(); //CLOSE
}
catch(Exception $e){
    $this->PDO->rollBack(); 
}
```

I need to insert as fastest possible data to db, because i get data from feed where more than 100 000 rows each 3 minutes.

Comment: You can answer your own question much better than anyone else if you are aware of what a transaction is. So - do you know what a transaction is and what it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest reading this [PHP PDO Transactions Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php).

First off, there's no difference if you explicitly begin a transaction, execute a PDOStatement, and commit that transaction or just simply execute the transaction.

Second, if the four database functions are dependent on each other, wrap them all in a transaction.

Third, regardless of whether or not the functions are related, wrapping them in a single transaction will definitely be faster.

Comment: Ok, i wrap it in one transaction. Thank you for advice.